# Can I use sub queries and a join in the same statement in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

This problem has left me clueless. I am trying to use a Join in mysql and a subquery and I keep getting a syntax error.

The statement in question is

```sql
SELECT Customer.customer_id, Customer.name, Order.address FROM Customer 
WHERE customer_id = (SELECT customer_id FROM Order WHERE customer_id = "625060836f7496e9fce3bbc6") 
INNER JOIN Order ON Customer.customer_id=Order.customer_id;
```

I have tried to just use the query without the Subquery and it works fine.

```sql
SELECT Customer.customer_id, Customer.name, Order.address FROM Customer  
INNER JOIN Order ON Customer.customer_id=Order.customer_id;
```

Removing the join but keeping the subquery also works.

```sql
SELECT Customer.customer_id, Customer.name, Order.address FROM Customer 
WHERE customer_id = (SELECT customer_id FROM Order WHERE customer_id = "625060836f7496e9fce3bbc6")
```

Only using both the subquery and the join results in a syntax error

I cannot seem to find the error.

What have I done wrong here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use them both, but `JOIN` clauses have to go before `WHERE`.

Comment: Why did you think a sub query would be helpful here I wonder - you haven't stated the problem you thought this approach useful for.

Answer (score 0):

The secret is to get the syntax right!

When querying more than one table it's good practice to use *aliases* to reference them and where multiple tables share the same column names, also string literals should be delimited with single 'quotes'.

In this specific example however the subquery is *superfluous*, just use the string literal directly in the where clause.

```
SELECT c.customer_id, c.name, o.address 
FROM Customer c
JOIN Order o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
WHERE c.customer_id = (
  SELECT customer_id 
  FROM Order 
  WHERE customer_id = '625060836f7496e9fce3bbc6'
);
```